# How to configure Python and pip Correctly

Tags: python, pip, apple-m1

I have an M1 Mac and I've realized that when I install using pip, python does not recognize. I can get away with this by using a venv, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried removing and Python and reinstalling, however, that does nothing to remedy the issue:
`which python3` yields `/usr/bin/python3`
`which pip3` yields `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip3`
`which pip` yields `/opt/homebrew/bin/pip`

Here is where the site location is: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

I do see that 3.10 and 3.9 are not the same but I'm not entirely sure how to change.

I've tried targeting the location using `pip -t` but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: use virtual environment and work with those one, ignore system one

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have multiple Python installations, and the paths are not properly set up.
You can use package manager like Homebrew to manage your Python installations.

https://brew.sh/

Once Homebrew is installed, you can use it to install a fresh copy of Python.

```
brew install python@3.9
```

once installed, check version:

```
python3 --version
```

Now, to ensure that you're using the correct Python and pip versions, you can update your PATH environment variable. Open the ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc file (depending on your shell) in a text editor:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin:$PATH"
```

Restart your Terminal to apply the changes: